# Debian 9 /var/log/ message, syslog,dmesg are these safe to post to a forum?

Tags: debian, syslog, dmesg

On a very stock Debian 9 VPS, running a multiplayer game system with very expensive scripting in it. I am having a problem with that multiplayer server, and one the server developers is asking me to publicly post my  /var/log/ syslog, and dmesg. Are these safe to post to a forum? Do they contain code snippets, or linux server passwords or user names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it wont contain code snippets or linux server passwords, it is a command on most Unix-like operating systems that prints the message buffer of the kernel. The output of this command typically contains the messages produced by the device drivers.